# jquery-ui icons not showing in production environment

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

jQuery-UI icons are not showing up on my production server. In the browser console, they come up as 404 and fail to load. They work fine locally on development, so I'm not sure what could be going wrong.

I'm using a custom theme, which is located in the images subdirectory under vendor/assets/stylesheets.

Does anyone know what could be causing these icons not to show in production?

I've tried changing the paths to the urls in the css and precompiling assets on production already.

Here is how I have it set up:

```
vendor
 assets
  stylesheets
    images
     **icons and custom theme**
    jquery-ui.css
```

**application.css.scss**

```
  *= require_self
  *= require foundation_and_overrides
  *= require slick
  *= require slick-theme
  *= require jquery-ui
  *= require main
  */
```

**Image Paths**

Here is one of the images not loading in production

```
 .ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
   background-image: url("images/ui-icons_469bdd_256x240.png");
 }
```

Comment: Hi, check the icon paths in the css file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Asset Pipeline fingerprinting to work, you need to use rails' helpers in your CSS file:

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
  background-image: url(<%= asset_path "images/ui-icons_469bdd_256x240.png" %>);
}
```

More details [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up adding an '.scss' extension to the css file and similar to your answer used an asset helper.